# Windows command line list all directories

Tags: windows, command-line

I'm looking to grab a list of the directories into a text document using a .bat file or the command line.

The problem I'm facing is that I have roughly twelve hard drives with a few folders in it, then inside those directories are around 163 more folders and I have to catalog them all.
Doing this by hand would be a huge task and I'm looking to simplify it.

If you need any more information please just ask and I will provide it.

Comment: do you simply want to list the directories, or all the files in the directories?

Comment: "`dir/s`" lists everything in every directory.  "`dir/AD`" lists directories only. "`tree`" lists subdirectories.

Comment: Just the directories, as the folders contain video files and assets, I just need to know the 'project'(folder) name

Answer (score 3):

You can try different params like /s. How you will do in multiple drives is another matter. You'd end up writing a .bat file which loops through different drives and run the command below. Or simply run this from every drive and collate the results.

```
dir /s > fileNames.txt
```

The above will create a fileNames.txt with all dir names.

HTH

Comment: +1.  In Win Server 2008 R2 64-Bit, this command listed all files not just folders.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
tree C: > out.txt
tree D: >> out.txt
...
tree Z: >> out.txt
```

You will need to do some editing, but the escape characters do help with the heirarchy.

Comment: The tree structure does not encode properly in a text file for me. Do I need a particular encoding?

Comment: It probably just does not render as you expect based upon your text editor.  If you are using Notepad++ from the main menu select Encoding > Character sets > Western European > OEM-850.  Any OEM should work regardless of your language base.

Answer (score 0):

You want the `dir` command with the flag `/s`.